# Laravel Echo does not listen for public channel events?

Tags: javascript, laravel, websocket, laravel-echo

I am using Laravel Websockets package.Everything looks great on server side but Laravel Echo is not listening to events..
**MySocketEvent.php:**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;

class MySocketEvent implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;
    public $data;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($data)
    {
        //
        $this->data=$data;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new Channel('DemoChannel.1');
    }

    public function broadcastAs()
{
    return 'testing';
}
}
```

**Web.php**

```php
Route::get('tests',function(){

    $arr=['some'=>'some'];

    broadcast(new \App\Events\MySocketEvent($arr));
    return view('hi');


});
```

**Bootstrap.js**

```js
import Echo from 'laravel-echo';

window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');

window.Echo = new Echo({
   

    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    //key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    key: 'my-key',
    wsHost: window.location.hostname,
    wsPort: 6001,
    wssPort: 6001,

    disableStats: true,
    cluster: 'ap2',
    //cluster: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
    //encrypted: true
});


//subscribe-for-the-test-demo-channel-and-listen

window.Echo.channel('DemoChannel.1')
    .listen('.testing', (e) => {
        console.log("Received Data: ");
        console.log(e);
    });
```

I see the data sent from server by using php artisan WebSockets:serve but Laravel Echo does not listen. Please help. I'm 100% sure problem is with Laravel Echo.

Answer (score 0):

The "dot" before "testing"

Broadcasting As "**testing**"

Listening For "**.testing**"

Replace this

```
window.Echo.channel('DemoChannel.1')
.listen('.testing', (e) => {
    console.log("Received Data: ");
    console.log(e);
});
```

To this

```
window.Echo.channel('DemoChannel.1')
.listen('testing', (e) => {
    console.log("Received Data: ");
    console.log(e);
});
```

**Update:**

Add this line to your event file

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcastNow;
```

Replace this

```
class MySocketEvent implements ShouldBroadcast
```

To this

```
class MySocketEvent implements ShouldBroadcastNow
```

Comment: also make sure you have broadcast_driver set to pusher in your .env file

Comment: try clearing caches. php artisan cache:clear , php artisan config:cache , php artisan route:cache

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get Echo working by downgrading pusher to 4.4.0

`npm install pusher-js@4.4.0`